# Run python script automatically every 3 days with launchd (mac)

Tags: python, macos, cron, scheduled-tasks, launchd

I am trying to automatically run a python script **every 3 days**.

What I am trying to accomplish is that the script is scheduled for every 3 days and if at that time the computer is offline, the job should be run **immediately** with startup and then again at the next scheduled time. Launchd does not seem to permit this, at least not directly, if I am not mistaken.

Do you know how to set this specific condition into a launchd script?

**StartInterval** seems not to be the correct solution.

```
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>600</integer>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

use the shed module for this task heres how it works: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=61A9A3C2EE904C8390C83AFB4AF75D87

Comment: Link-only answers may become outdated. We would ask that you include the essential parts in this answer and only provide the link for further reference, (not the complete solution).